# R- Monte Carlo Poker Hand Counter

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm trying to throw together a project for practice.  I'm trying to count poker hands in a Monte Carlo simulation using R.

I'm getting stuck on how to handle my straights, straight flushes, and royal flushes.  Code for the straights and straight flushes are not included, but I did attempt to "pseudo-code" a royal flush.  I'm hoping that if I can get some direction on my royal flush, that I can figure out how to handle straight flushes and straights.  The code ran as intended before I added the code for the royalflush.  Code below:

```
poker.sim <- function (Msim=10000,n=5) {
# This is a function to simulate Poker draws from a standard card deck
# We will be using a Grand Loop approach 
#
# Create the card deck
denom = rep(c("A",2:10,"J","Q","K"),4)
suit = rep(c("S","H","D","C"),each=13)
carddeck = data.frame(denom,suit)


# Initialize the twosuit, onepair, twopair, threeofakind, flush, fullhouse, and fourofakind as counters and for storage later...

count.twosuit = 0
count.onepair = 0
count.twopair = 0
count.threeofakind = 0
count.flush = 0
count.fullhouse = 0
count.fourofakind = 0
count.royalflush = 0


# Begin the Grand Loop
for(i in 1:Msim) 
    {
    # determine card numbers for this hand
    select = sample(nrow(carddeck),n)
    # select rows from the card deck for this hand
    hand = carddeck[select,]


        # Check for TWOSUIT and increment the counter if twosuit occurs
        # This statement is counting every instance in which only two suits occur in a five-card hand.

        if(length(unique(hand[,2]))==2) count.twosuit = count.twosuit+1


        # Check for ONEPAIR and increment the counter if onepair occurs
        # What this loop is doing is setting the length of the hand to 4 possible cards.
        # The first, second, and third cards can be any cards occurring only once.
        # The last two cards must be the same.
        tab = sort(table(as.vector(hand[,1])))

        if(length(tab) ==4)
            {
            if(all(tab == c(1,1,1,2))) count.onepair = count.onepair+1
            }


        # Check for TWOPAIR and increment the counter if twopair occurs
        # What this loop is doing is setting the length of the hand to be 3 possible cards.
        # The first card will occur only once.
        # The last two cards will occur twice each.

        if(length(tab) ==3)
            {
            if(all(tab == c(1,2,2))) count.twopair = count.twopair+1
            }


        # Check for THREEOFAKIND and increment the counter if threeofakind occurs.
        # What this function is doing is setting the length of the hand to 3 possible cards.
        # The first and second cards occur once each and can be any card.
        # The last three cards must be the same.

        if(length(tab) ==3) 
            {
            if(all(tab == c(1,1,3))) count.threeofakind = count.threeofakind+1
            }


        # Check for FLUSH and increment the counter if a flush occurs.
        # This statement is counting every instance in which only one suit occurs in a five-card hand.

        if (length(unique(hand[,2]))==1) count.flush = count.flush+1


        #Check for a FULLHOUSE and increment the counter if fullhouse occurs
        # What this loop is doing is setting the length of the hand to 2 possible cards.
        # The first occurring twice, and the second occurring 3 times.  Or vice versa.

        if(length(tab) ==2)
            {
            if(all(tab == c(2,3))) count.fullhouse = count.fullhouse+1
            }


        # Check for FOUROFAKIND and increment the counter if fourofakind occurs.
        # What this loop is doing is setting the length of the hand to 2 possible cards.
        # The first occurring only once, and the second occurring 4 times.

        if(length(tab) ==2)
            {
            if(all(tab == c(1,4))) count.fourofakind = count.fourofakind+1  
            }   


        # Check for ROYALFLUSH and increment the counter if royalflush occurs.
        # This will be restricted to only one suit AND when a run of 10,J,Q,K,A occurs.

        if(length(unique(hand[,2]))==1) 
        {
        if(tab == c(10,J,Q,K,A) count.royalflush = count.royalflush+1 
        }


    } # Close the Grand Loop


# Then, we will count the twosuits, onepairs, twopairs, threeofakinds, flushes, fullhouses, and fourofakinds 
# and divide them by the number of iterations of the simulation to get their respective probabilities.

p.twosuit = count.twosuit/Msim
p.onepair = count.onepair/Msim
p.twopair = count.twopair/Msim
p.threeofakind = count.threeofakind/Msim
p.flush = count.flush/Msim
p.fullhouse = count.fullhouse/Msim
p.fourofakind = count.fourofakind/Msim
p.royalflush = count.royalflush/Msim



# To output the results
out = list(Msim,p.twosuit,p.onepair,p.twopair,p.threeofakind,p.flush,p.fullhouse,p.fourofakind,p.royalflush)
names(out) = c("Msim","p.twosuit","p.onepair","p.twopair","p.threeofakind","p.flush","p.fullhouse","p.fourofakind","p.royalflush")
out
}
```

Comment: Could you be more precise what exactly you need help with?

Comment: My line of code for counting a royal flush does not work.  That is the specific line I need help with.

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo, but `c(10,J,Q,K,A)` should probably be `c("10","J","Q","K","A")`

Comment: I have tried both ways, and that didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: I copied your code and I see that there is a parenthesis missing in `if(tab == c(10,J,Q,K,A)`. It should be `if(tab == c(10,J,Q,K,A))`. Also, J,Q,K,A must be strings as R tries to treat them as objects and fails throwing an error as those objects don't exist.

Comment: I'm getting an error.  It is saying there is an unexpected "{"

Comment: I fixed what you asked me to fix.  Did you see how I initialized "tab" and "hand".  Am I using them correctly in this specific instance?

Comment: hand = carddeck[select,]
 tab = sort(table(as.vector(hand[,1])))

Comment: They are initialized ok. In this instance, checking if all are of same suit is ok, but whether you have the right values of cards won't work. You can check my answer for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing only on the royal flush part, I think your logic of checking if the cards are 10,J,Q,K,A doesn't work. I would instead use [`setqual`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) to check if the elements of `hand[, 1]` are the same as the vector `c("10","J","Q","K","A")`.
Thus we have:

```
if(length(unique(hand[ , 2])) == 1) 
{
  if(setequal(hand[ , 1], c("10","J","Q","K","A")))
    count.royalflush = count.royalflush + 1 
}
```

---

For checking if we have a straight, we'll need a bit more complex condition. We'll create a function that checks for a straight

```
is_straight <- function(hand) {
  # first we want to encode "J", "Q", "K" to 11, 12, 13, so we can use diff later
  # we take the denominators from the hand as a character vector
  hand_denom <- as.character(hand[ , 1])
  # and then map acording values
  hand_denom[hand_denom == "J"] <- 11
  hand_denom[hand_denom == "Q"] <- 12
  hand_denom[hand_denom == "K"] <- 13

  # we need to check whether we treat ace as high or low and encode it accordingly
  # if any of the cards is a two, then ace will be treated as 1 if it's a straight
  # otherwise, we'll treat it as 14
  hand_denom[hand_denom == "A"] <- ifelse(any(hand_denom == "2"), 1, 14)

  # now we just check if the numeric values are successive (i.e. diff is always 1)
  all(diff(sort(as.numeric(hand_denom))) == 1)
}
```

and you obviously use this in your code as `if (is_straight(hand)) <straight handling>`.

Comment: You've been a huge help.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to code for just a straight flush.  How would I set it to just check for any run of 5 in a row? For a royal flush, we specified the top 5 denominations.

Comment: Hmm that's a bit trickier, mostly the problem is that ace can be high and low, so we need to handle that. I'll try and write something up and put it in the answer.